# Howto pipe raw PCM-Data from /dev/ttyUSB0 to soundcard?

Tags: unix, audio, pipe, pcm

I'm working currently on a small microhpone, connected to PC via an FPGA. The FPGA spits a raw datastream via UART/USB into my computer. I'm able to record, play and analyze the data.

But I can't play the "live" audiostream directly.

What works is saving the datastream in PCM raw-format with a custom made C-program, and piping the content of the file into aplay. But that adds a 10sec lag into the datastream... Not so nice for demoing or testing.

```
tail -f snd.raw | aplay -t raw -f S16_LE -r 9000
```

Does someone have another idea, how get the audiostream faster into my ears? Why does

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | aplay
```

not work? (nothing happens)

Thanks so far
marvin

Comment: does the custom C program do anything other than opening the device node and reading from it?

Comment: yep. it's custom made, just for this purpose. it logs in raw, wav and matlab-style

Comment: Do you have the source code for the custom program? If yes, describe what it does. Otherwise, run it using `strace(1)` and post a log of its activity.

Comment: Hm, will this be usefull? Actually I'm looking more in the direction of cat'ing directly from the tty, to get rid of my crappy C-code

The program does just reading from tty (using strace i can see that ~10bytes are read each iteration) and writing to the files, in endless loop. Nothing special.

Comment: Well, you should verify that your little utility really does nothing other than reading from the device node. For a serial device, it is likely that some sort of setup needs to be done first.

Comment: Setup of the serial device is done before the read-write-loop, yes. And reading from the device with read() works, so I assume that my initialization is correct.

But: When I set the state of the device with stty to the exact same state as when my program is running, cat'ing does not work... why?

Answer (score 1):

You need an api that lets you stream audiobuffers directly to the soundcard.  I haven't done it on Linux, but I've used [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org) for this purpose.   You might find another API in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772208/best-audio-playback-api-for-c-c-under-linux).  SDL seems popular.

The general idea is that you set up a streaming buffer, then your c program stuffs the incoming bytes into an array.  The size is chosen to balance lag with jitter in the incoming stream.  When the array is full, you pass it to the API, and start filling another one while the first plays.

Answer (score 1):

That would seem to be the domain of the `alsaloop` program.  However, this program requires two ALSA devices to work with and you can see from its options that it goes to considerable effort in order to match the data flow of the devices, something that you would not necessarily want to do yourself.

[This Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134751/how-to-register-a-virtual-card-to-alsa-from-user-space) talks about how to create a virtual userspace device available to ALSA: maybe that is a route worth pursuing.