# How to register a virtual card to alsa from user-space?

Tags: linux, audio, kernel, device, virtualization

I'm developing a virtual device from the user space

(using umview http://wiki.virtualsquare.org/wiki/index.php/UMview)
so, i need to register my device to the system's sound cards list

(I've never used alsa in a kernel module so I think that I need to call the snd_card_register() function)

but I can't find a way to do that from the userspace...

maybe I can write a syscall to do that?

Comment: I believe that ALSA handles virtual devices in the libasound library completely out of kernel. You just define something in the config and the applications will use it. I never understood the config though; it is somewhat arcane.

Comment: I've never heard of umview before, but from a quick look it seems you'd simply have to redefine reading from the card list. Kernel isn't handling the device, it shouldn't know about it either. But umview shouldn't be needed for creating alsa virtual device in the first place I believe.

Comment: Thx for the response.
It's a little more complex..
simply umview hijack every syscall to a designed file
(you simply do a $mount -t umaudiomixer none /dev/snd/controlC0, and he mount my module over the card 0 mixer file) every open/read/write/close/ioctl to this file is hijacked to my module and i can redefine the results of every operation (without passing the syscall to the underlying kernel)

so I need the /dev/snd/XXX hook file to the "virtual" device..
unfortunately I don't understand the config too, and i don't see a way to "create" my virtual device in /dev/snd or in another place
:(

Comment: I think you have to do everything with libasound directly (i.e. don't create `/dev/snd/anythinng`, create whatever libasound is willing to accept) or everything with umview (override the special file from which list of devices is read too).

Comment: mmmh...the second approach you have described It's more likely to what i want...you are saying that I need to do a mount of my module on an existing device? so a thing like $mount -t umdevaudiomixer none /dev/snd/controlC0 with a real existing card 0 alsa device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem some times ago,

Alsa user-space lib simply open every /dev/snd/controlC# from 0 to 32 and launch

```
ioctl(SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_CARD_INFO, ...);
```

in order to build a list with the installed sound-cards

if we mount our UmView module on /dev/snd/control# and we hijack the ioctl and answer to it, our module will be identified as a sound-card by ALSA

I've created a virtual sound device with that technique, you can find it at
https://github.com/berdav/umdevaudio

this is a simple way to build a simple user-space driver.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should stop bothering about overriding any particular file (i.e. *stop* using umview, it's not needed) and simply use the ["file" plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html) to create device in the [ALSA config](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) that will *pipe* the data to your virtual device over a named pipe in `/var/run/virtualsound/output` or somewhere like that.

Unlike the umview approach, this will work in all applications without having to run them in any special way.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) It's a very good approach, but I wanted to do the umview way to "bind" the virtual device to my virtual machine (and umview lack of a virtual sound device)...so I need to create my device only visible in my umview VM, so all application that's running inside the umview instance can use my device and all application outside no  (something like a QEMU or any other emulator sound device)...I've started with the famous motto "everything is a file" in my mind...but now I don't think that's really true :(