# Play .mp3 or other audio files in linux using C++

Tags: c++, linux, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best audio playback api for C/C++ under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772208/best-audio-playback-api-for-c-c-under-linux)

I am looking for a library with which i can play a audio file using C++ code in linux , any suggestions ?

Edit : Please include the links of some tutorials if it's possible .

Comment: Check out [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).

Comment: Look at Qt and Phonon. Qt also will be cross-platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772208/best-audio-playback-api-for-c-c-under-linux?rq=1

Comment: Be more specific. If you are doing 3d games use OpenAL else try libao, ffmpeg, gstreamer, etc

Comment: @quarry I just want to play a audio files when some text appears on my application . It happens rarely and it's not a game;it's a simple application .

Comment: Found some examples for SDL audio , it looks good .

Comment: @Sergey using Qt's audio API is a pain even in 2014.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [FMOD](https://www.fmod.com/download). It is a cross-platform audio library for C++.

There are quite a few tutorials available, such as these:

- [Quick Guide to FMOD](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-quick-guide-to-fmod-r2098)
- [FMOD Introduction](http://jerome.jouvie.free.fr/nativefmodex/tutorials/Tutorial01.php?run=Win)

Comment: Why the -1? It's what the OP wants...

Comment: Yup that's what i wanted , Thanks .